# When i try to run my program, the GUI won't load and I can't figure out why

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, jpanel

This part of the code works fine when not using arrays or arraylists.

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class GUI
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("01");
        frame.getContentPane().add(new Panel());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

This part of the code works fine when not using arrays or arraylists

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Panel extends JPanel
{
    private Shapes shapes;

    public Panel () {
        setFocusable(true);
        requestFocusInWindow();
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics gc) {
        super.paintComponent(gc);
        shapes.draw(gc);
    }
}
```

In this class if I don't use arrays or arraylists it runs fine, but I can't make it work with them.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Shapes
{

    ArrayList <int[]> blocks = new ArrayList <int[]>();

    int[] arr;
    int w,x,y,z;

    public void draw(Graphics gc) {
        gc.setColor(Color.black);
        blocks();
        for(int i=0; i<blocks.size()-1; i++){
            w=blocks.get(i)[0];
            x=blocks.get(i)[1];
            y=blocks.get(i)[2];
            z=blocks.get(i)[3];
            gc.fillRect(w, x, y, z);
        }
    }

    public void blocks() {
        popBlocks(100,500,300,30);
        popBlocks(300,400,150,30);
        popBlocks(500,300,150,30);
        popBlocks(700,200,150,30);
        popBlocks(900,100,150,30);
    }

    private void popBlocks(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
        arr[0] = a;
        arr[1] = b;
        arr[2] = c;
        arr[3] = d;
        blocks.add(arr);
    }
}
```

Comment: What problems/errors are you having? Is there any stacktrace you can add to your answer?

Comment: In queue terms what you're doing is "push".  "pop" usually _removes_ an element from a queue.

Answer (score 1):

`NullPointerException` in `Panel#paintComponent` because `shapes` is not initialized...

```
public class Panel extends JPanel {

    private Shapes shapes;

    public Panel() {
        shapes = new Shapes();
```

`NullPointerException` in `Shapes#popBlocks` because `arr` is not initialised

```
public class Shapes
{
    //...    
    int[] arr = new int[4];
    //...
```

But wait, that only draws a single shape?!  All this is doing is updating the instance of `arr` with some new values and adding it to the `blocks` `List`

```
private void popBlocks(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    arr[0] = a;
    arr[1] = b;
    arr[2] = c;
    arr[3] = d;
    blocks.add(arr);
}
```

This means you have 5 blocks with the values of `900,100,150,30`.

Instead of using an instance field, you should make `arr` a method level field, for example...

```
public class Shapes
{
    //...    
    //int[] arr;
    //...

    private void popBlocks(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
        int[] arr = new int[4];
        arr[0] = a;
        arr[1] = b;
        arr[2] = c;
        arr[3] = d;
        blocks.add(arr);
    }
}
```

Also, the `for-loop` in the `draw` method is wrong, it should be looping from `0-size - 1`, not `0-size - 2`, for example

```
public void draw(Graphics gc) {
    //...
    for(int i=0; i < blocks.size(); i++){
        //...
```

Comment: `arr` is a class-level variable, so they won't get NPE.  They still won't get what they want, though...

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse I couldn't see anywhere `arr` was declared, so it must be `null`, by removing the class level variable and making it a method level variable (and initialising it), the OP should now be getter the 5 shapes they defined ... I'm not able to test the code, so I'm relying on my "awesome" desk checking skills

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse *"I couldn't see anywhere arr was declared"* - sorry, initialised :P

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse In fact, once I had time to run the code, there are **2** `NullPointerExceptions`, one exactly where I predicted it would be, but I had to correct for another one first

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'm relatively new to programming, how would I initialize arr as a method level variable?

Comment: See my example of popBlocks

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0; i<blocks.size()-1; i++){
```

condition on the for loop is wrong that should be

```
for(int i=0; i<=blocks.size()-1; i++) . 
or
for(int i=0; i<blocks.size(); i++)
```

you might wanna try this.